# Table active row scrolling the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to make my table rows selected when user uses arrow keys.
This is working nice as you can see below:

[image: example]

As you can see, the table is inside a div with

```
overflow:auto.
```

My issue is: I want to make the scroll bar follows the selected row when the user reach a row that is under the div limit.

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/alinedanawara/4spzwvh6/1/

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not working.

Comment: Do u mean the URL is broken or the script isn't running? If you're talking about the script, you have to click the result page after using arrow keys. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a `scrollTop` in your highlight function to keep the highlighted item at the top of the list as long as possible based on your tableIndex variable and the height of a row:

```
$('#areaItens').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#data tbody tr:eq('+tableIndex+')').height() * tableIndex
}, 0);
```

This will ensure the container is showing the highlighted item. You can play with a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wsL8381q/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. 
Scroll to the top when the highlighted element goes below the viewport.

```
var parent = $("#areaItens");
var currentEl = $('#data tbody tr:eq(' + tableIndex + ')');
if (currentEl.offset().top > parent.height()) {
  parent[0].scrollTop = currentEl[0].offsetTop;
}
if (currentEl.offset().top < 0) {
  parent[0].scrollTop = currentEl[0].offsetTop - parent.height() + $('#data tbody tr').first().height();
  }
}
```

Here is a demo **https://jsfiddle.net/4spzwvh6/3/**

If you want the highlighted cell to be always on the top it can be done like this

```
var parent = $("#areaItens");
var currentEl = $('#data tbody tr:eq(' + tableIndex + ')');
parent[0].scrollTop = currentEl[0].offsetTop;
```

Here is a demo for the above **https://jsfiddle.net/4spzwvh6/4/**